# Facebook Like Button

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-like

Clicking "Like" on my site will show up in my profile feed, but not my news feed, which means other people don't see it.

I'm using WordPress.

Anyone else having this problem and know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the best results from the Facebook like button you need to do an XFBML integration.  This allows you to post an image, a comment, and some additional information about the page/post that is being liked.  When you do this, Facebook will promote it more in the news feed.

For a detailed tutorial on how to set this up in Wordpress, check out this post:

http://abecoffman.com/2011/advanced-wordpress-like-button-integration/

Answer (score 1):

Your news feed often does not have your own posts, as Facebook assumes you know what you are posting. It should appear in other peoples feeds (depending on activity/popularity etc)